# Android, MQTT: broker certificate expiration

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

My app connects to mqtt broker using certificate file through ssl connection.

I setup the certificate file (.crt) and the key file (.key) in my broker.

I use Paho Mqtt Client api, and this api needs a SSLSocketFactory to establish connection.

I use a Google example to create a SSLSocketFactory instance with a TrustManager who trust our CA in a keystore.

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new 
FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;

try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

Everything works fine right now. BUT, the certificate is going to expire in 5/30/2017.

How do i must deal with the certificate in the client side (Android)?

I've have tested in testing environment with a new certificate. The app can't connect to broker. Exception is:

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

How can a deal with certificate renewal on Android?

Comment: Do you mean revocation or renewal rather than "renovation"? Also renewing certificates and distributing them to a device will be entirely dependant on the CA you are using.

Comment: @hardillb I mean renewal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have request a new certificate using the same .key file and all clients did not have any issue connecting to broker with the new .crt.

But, is it safe to use the same key for certificate renewal?